# Validation of Models with Different Scale Data

Tags: r, cross-validation, modeling, normalization

I created a model for two different datasets that have different scales. When checking which one performed better, I am struggling with figuring out the best methodology. My top choices right now are `R^2`, `RMSE`, and `variance`. However, R^2 seems to be the only option that works best in my opinion because it doesn't seem to take into account the scale of the data but wondering if there are options such as normalizing the numbers etc.

Below is a sample situation:

```
      Date      Group      Actual_Values       Predicted_Values
2020-04-24          A              0.181                  0.140
2020-04-27          A              0.190                  0.127
2020-04-28          A              0.188                  0.126
2020-04-29          A              0.188                  0.123
2020-04-30          A              0.185                  0.122
2020-05-01          A              0.178                  0.124
2020-05-04          A              0.182                  0.118
2020-05-05          A              0.180                  0.120
2020-05-06          A              0.178                  0.120
2020-05-07          A              0.180                  0.121
2020-05-08          A              0.184                  0.124

2020-04-24          B              86.24                  86.25
2020-04-27          B              94.00                  86.65
2020-04-28          B              98.44                  86.88
2020-04-29          B              107.3                  87.05
2020-04-30          B              94.26                  87.27
2020-05-01          B              96.71                  87.42
2020-05-04          B              92.28                  87.59
2020-05-05          B              90.97                  87.73
2020-05-06          B              87.47                  87.80
2020-05-07          B              88.93                  87.90
2020-05-08          B              92.41                  87.93
```

From this dataset I tested the following code:

```
library(ModelMetrics)
with_rmse<- historical_results %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(
    RMSE = rmse(Predicted_Values, Actual_Values)
    ,R2 = cor(Predicted_Values, Actual_Values)^2
    ,variance = abs(var(Predicted_Values, Actual_Values))
  )

Group           RMSE            R2      variance
    A     0.05929241    0.02067078  3.548883e-06   
    B       8.461625    0.02991999     0.5624356
```

So for example, the above results like `8.4` for `RMSE` may actually be good but looks bad just because the original values were higher than `A`. Any help would be great, thanks! This is just an example - disregard the bad R2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMSE depends on scale -> consider relative RMSE e.g. $rRMSE = \frac{RMSE}{\bar y}$

The same strategy can be applied to variance, but keep in mind its dimension is the square of the dimension of your dependent.

Answer (score 1):

1. R^2 still isn't a good measure as we know that by just adding more features we can overfit.  If you're only comfortable using R^2, try adjusted R^2 which penalizes additional features. AIC is a relatively better metric to compare linear models.
2. Make sure the residuals are random and you aren't missing any obvious relationships.
3. For starters, just run a Anova test to compare the 2 models